# Batch Jobs with Grails

Tags: grails, groovy

I work with a company that is beginning to use Grails 1.3.7 (yes, outdated, as this is the only version the vendor supports) and Groovy. We want to base our system on grails to run batch database jobs and eventually implement a web interface. What is the idiomatic way to write batch database jobs into grails and have it run on a regular schedule? Preferably without plugins, is there a way?

Alternatively, should we only use groovy scripts to run the batch jobs and put them into an old fashioned cron job, and if so, how can we extract the database connection from the WAR file or tomcat server (via JNDI)?  I made some simple groovy scripts that connected to our Oracle db with hard-coded database information but probably don't want to do it that way going forward.

Perhaps there is a good beginners book that I can get to familiarize myself with grails as well?

Thanks,

Tom

Comment: I bet you could find the Grails book by searching. Whether or not it's a good choice for you right now... Debatable. It didn't really sound like you'll actually be able to use it.

Comment: Seems like Grails probably isn't the best tool for this job. Grails is for writing web applications, not managing database jobs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quartz plugin is the way to go. However, if you must insist on not using the plugin, you can still add the quartz jars themselves on the project's classpath (by editing BuildConfig.groovy) and by using [Spring's support for talking to Quartz](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html).

In turn, you can let Grails communicate with Spring, as [described in the Grails manual](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/spring.html). That also works in Grails 1.3.x

Comment: Ah, the most helpful reply yet, thanks Hans!  I'll look into that.  I'd 1-up your response but it told me I needed a reputation of 15 and I'm new to stackoverflow.

Comment: glad to help... and there's always the option of flagging my response as the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Your statements about not supporting grails 2x and not wanting to use plugins are alarming and raising red flags. If you can't use a particular framework as it was designed to to be used perhaps there are other alternatives that are better for you ...  Having said that, I would encourage you to use the latest version of Grails as it brings benefits as well as better support going forward.

As far as running database batch jobs .. perhaps the best thing to do is just run them from a database. Oracle DB has a great **jobs scheduler** that works great.

If you do need to run the server side code on schedule then I would recommend **Quartz** plugin. It is very easy to setup and use, and comes with fairly good documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the responses!  I did not say I wouldn't use plugins, I just hoped there was a way without.  If the quartz plugin is that great, I will definitely consider it.  I understand that Groovy and Grails is primarily web, though I have found numerous instances while searching of people utilizing it for batch jobs as well.  In fact, Spring has a batch plugin that I will be looking into so I don't buy that Grails isn't good for batch.  As for the Grails book, yes I did a search and I found a whole lot of books.  Now to find the one that might be the best fit for me is the hard part...

Comment: And as far as not supporting grails 2x, we are constrained by the vendor delivering the software package we purchased eons ago.  While they are currently working to get their product certified to 2x I am not going to move forward with it until they have certified it and support it.  Our app still needs to work regardless of what I'm doing with batch.  While I agree that this is not optimal, it is what it is.  We can move to 2x when we're ready.

Comment: @user2544740 another vote here for the Quartz plugin, I use it extensively in several projects to manage many overlapping asynchronous jobs (mainly monitoring the health of external resources that the webapp manages) and it's never failed me yet.  To my mind, Grails is all about the plugin ecosystem - remember that even apparently core things like Hibernate (for database access) are implemented as plugins.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult because you don't want to use plugin, as quartz is very easy to use and will suit your need.

You can try this hack as an alternative.  Create a service that contains the logic of your batch job, and then create a controller action that invoke that service.

Then create a cron job from your operating system, invoking that controller action.  Perhaps using wget or something custom written.  This is only a hack I could think of, and not good and secure.